# Uppercase index Title with fncychap

Tags: lyx, fncychap

Hi I'm using LyX and with \usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap} in preamble.

The tile of TOC or Index List is lowercase but i want it uppercase.

what command and where I must write in for do what i want?

Answer (score 1):

Use `tocloft` package:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
\usepackage{tocloft}

%\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of contents} % change "Contents" to "Table of Contents"
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\center\hfill\large\bfseries\MakeUppercase} % change toc title to upper case
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}
%\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\scshape} %For uppercase TOC entries

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Foo1}
Some text.

\chapter{Foo2}
Some text.

\end{document}
```